# C# Reading CSV fields including whitespaces in the fields to process XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, csv, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read a CSV file using C# and process the XML based on the values in it. My code is working fine if the fields in the CSV are without spaces, i.e. `age`, but failing when the field is like `First Name`. How do I read that entire string using C#?

I have only 2 columns in the CSV:

```
Customer,id
Customer,age
Customer,sex
Customer,First Name     
Address,Street
Address,Street Id      
Custom,Applicant Last Name
Custom,Social Security -CB
```

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace DataScrub_Test
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String[] lines =  System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Input\test1.csv");
            List<string> Parent = new List<string>();
            List<string> Node = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                Parent.Add(values[0]);
                Node.Add(values[1]);
                Console.WriteLine(Parent[0]);
            }

            var doc = XDocument.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\Jason\\Desktop\\Input\\2015\\09\\03\\filename.xml"));
            for (int i = 0; i < Parent.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (var p in doc.Descendants(Parent[i]))
                {
                    var nodevar = p.Attribute(Node[i]);
                    if (nodevar != null)
                    {
                        nodevar.Remove();
                    }

                }
                var result = doc.Descendants("CustomField").Where(x => x.Attribute("text").Value == Node[i]);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        result.Remove();
                    }
            }
doc.Save("C:\\Users\\Jason\\Desktop\\Input\\2015\\09\\03\\filename.xml");
        }
    }

}
```

The Exception I'm getting is:

> The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a
>   name.

And the exception is arising at this line: `var nodevar = p.Attribute(Node[i]);`

Comment: What do you mean by failing?

Comment: There are no commas, so Id expect it to completely fail and return you just lines of text

Comment: What is the delimiter at all? A tab? Because if it's really a comma i expect more problems, f.e. if an address contains a comma. Use a real csv parser like the .NET `TextFieldParser`-class.

Comment: There are no commas in your **C**omma **S**eparated-**V**alues. What is your separator? Spaces? If so, how will you differentiate between desirable and undesirable spaces? Even though there is no real standard for CSV, without a standard separator, this doesn't look much like CSV.

Comment: Sorry , the delimiter is  , (comma)

By failing, I mean my code gives an exception there

Comment: @HadoopAddict If you're getting an Exception, you need to tell us what it is and which line it's happening on.

Comment: You need to normalize that name. The exception is telling you that the white space ` ` in `First Name` cannot be set as an attribute name

Comment: I cant normalize that because using that full string it need to find the node in xml and remove it.

Comment: @HadoopAddict You're using that string to find the node Attribute, not the node name itself

Comment: If I normalize it using _, how will it find the attribute because in the attribute it is space?

Comment: It's impossible that the attribute has a white space. Think of `First Name` with a value of `Jason`. If you write directly to the XML file you'll print something like this: `<customField First Name="Jason">`, but a normal XML processor will read it like two separate attributes, one `First` with an empty value, and another one `Name` with the value `Jason`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always make use of parsers, otherwise you'll go nuts if any text contains a `,` char.

```
TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(line));
parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
parser.SetDelimiters(",");

while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    var values = parser.ReadFields();

    Parent.Add(values[0]);
    Node.Add(values[1]);
```

**LAST QUESTION UPDATE**

You need to normalize that name. The exception is telling you that an attribute cannot contain a white space `' '` char (the one found in `First Name` i.e.).

A most used way is to normalize white spaces is to replace them for the underscore char `'_'`.

```
var nodevar = p.Attribute(Node[i].Replace(" ", "_"));
```

Comment: Don't forget to reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic`... but yes, using a "proper" parser is going to cause much less grief than rolling your own.

Comment: If performance is a concern, I'd rather use a regular split.
here's a benchmark: http://www.dotnetperls.com/textfieldparser

Comment: @TJL a simple `,` will make your data inconsistent, cause exceptions and a large etc. You can use the split approach but that implies that your file is not stored in CSV format, but in a format you control

Comment: I am using the csv to process the xml using c#. Please find the updated question. Thanks for the valuable inputs.

Comment: There's only a few variations tho for csv tho. You are concerning about quotation?

Comment: I'm concerning about this: `Custom, "description that contains, several commas, that you cannot parse with a simple split", Applicant Last Name`

Comment: sure. if it doesn't quote properly, more code has to be added. How would TextFieldParser help in such a case?

Comment: If it's not quoted propertly, **it is not** [CSV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules)

Comment: anyway, out of curiosity what makes TextFieldParser a better solution in this case?

Comment: In the short-term, you may find easier and faster to use a Split and solve the problem fast. In the long-term, applications tend to get more complex and scale. If you just store the values in a _pseudo_ csv format, when you try to send those to another web service that did implement that csv format in the proper way... you're screwed

Answer (score 0):

You can read entire string with space using this way

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Input\test1.csv");
List<string> Parent = new List<string>();
List<string> Node = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
   string[] values = line.Split(',');
   Parent.Add(values[0]);
   Node.Add(values[1]);
   Console.WriteLine(Parent[0]);
}
```

Comment: But I want the Column A (Part before comma) and Column B (part after comma) into 2 different lists.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I still get the same error. Please find the updated question .